# Differentiate pod based on MacOS and iOS for macCatalyst (Xcode 11 Beta 5)

Tags: ios, cocoapods, uikitformac, mac-catalyst

We are converting our iOS app to macCatalyst compatible using catalyst swift in xcode 11 beta 5.

I am facing issue in some pod files which are not yet supported for macCatalyst.

so, any one found solution in which we can differentiate pod based on MacOS and iOS. Using this **iOS pod only install of iPhone/iPad** and other for **macOS + iOS**

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the same problem, the conclusion is that until the developers of the hearth adapt it to the Mac Catalyst, it will not work under